# Returning container object from a filter rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a list TeamMember object:

```
class TeamMember {
    List<Sport> sports;
}
```

The task at hand is to return the team member which have an input sport.

I have achieved just this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(getTeamMembers())
    .flatMapIterable(teamMember -> teamMember.getSports())
    .filter(sport -> sport.equals(selectedSport))
```

However this would just returned a matched sport and my original team member has been lost.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest it inside one more `flatMap` and you will get access to `TeamMember` in lambda.

```
Observable.fromIterable(getTeamMembers())
        .flatMap(teamMember -> Observable.fromIterable(teamMember.getSports())
                .filter(sport -> sport.equals(selectedSport))
                .map(sportMatchingSelectedSport -> new TeamMemberWithSport(teamMember, sportMatchingSelectedSport)))
```